# How to - dynamically - change link text color in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile styles links according to the theme stylesheet. You can only change this if you use !important, thus:

```
.glossaryLink{
 color: white !important;
 background-color: #CC8DCC;   
}
```

What I need to do is dynamically change the colour of these links. These glossary links are highlighted in purple and we need to the ability to turn the highlighting off.

Using the following script I'm able to change the background color, but not the text colour:

```
$(".glossary_option").click(function(){
if(localStorage.glossaryopt=="off"){
  localStorage.glossaryopt = "on";
  $("#glossary_option").html("Highlighting ON"); 
  $(".glossaryLink").css({
    "color":"white",
    "background-color":"#CC8DCC"
    });
}else{
  localStorage.glossaryopt = "off";      
  $("#glossary_option").html("Highlighting OFF");
  $(".glossaryLink").css({
    "color":"black",
    "background-color":"white"
    });  
}
```

});

This turns the background white but doesn't turn the text black, even though inspecting the element in Chrome shows a css color of black.

I've tried using "black !important" but it doesn't work either.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You should add link HTML, how can we test our solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have previously added css color white with important. this wont overwrite css color black you are setting later on. You need to use:

```
.glossaryLink{
  color: white;
  background-color: #CC8DCC;   
}
```

Comment: You were right about it being my fault for setting the colour as !important in the first place. I thought I had to do that initially for some reason - it works fine now. I had tried your other method (said so in my question) but it seems you can't add !important values with the .css method.

Comment: Thats strange. i have updated the answer. but it did worked when i was setting the min-height property in my application.